# function defined in .zshrc not found when called from a script

Tags: function, scripting, zsh

I have defined some variables, aliases and functions in my .zshrc file:

```
export MY_VAR="example"

alias my_alias="echo an example"

function say_hello
{
    echo "say hello"
}
```

I have verified that all three are defined and whatnot when called from the terminal.  However, when I try to call the function say_hello from another script (which itself is called from the same terminal), the function does not appear to be defined. I see a 'command not found' error.  The alias and variable MY_VAR appear to be defined just fine when referenced from this other script.

Any ideas on what might be going on? Thanks.

Comment: How do you execute that other script? What's the first line in that other script (meaning is it actually using zsh instead of e.g. bash via `#!/bin/sh`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When zsh is called from a terminal it is invoked in interactive mode that causes zsh to source additional configuration files, including `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc` (`$HOME/.zshrc`). By default (in non-interactive mode in non-login shell) it sources only `/etc/zsh/zshenv`* and `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv` (`$ZDOTDIR` is most of time `$HOME`) files, see last but two section of `man zsh` named `STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES`. I have no idea why alias is defined (how exactly did you check?), but MY_VAR is defined in script because you exported it.

* `/etc/zshenv` according to doc, much likely they are Gentoo maintainers of zsh package who changed it to `/etc/zsh/zshenv`.

Note: it is bad idea to put such functions into `.zshenv` file as it creates *implicit* dependency. You should use script libraries instead: put it into

```
~/.zsh/say_hello.zsh
```

and do

```
source ${ZDOTDIR-$HOME}/.zsh/say_hello.zsh
```

in both your script and `.zshrc`.

Comment: ah this is the problem. thanks.  Kindof silly that I need yet a third shell configuration file, but at least it is a solution.

Comment: how did this solve your problem and why? I don't find this explanation clear enough. what was the exact problem that causes function definitions not to be defined?